# Getting frequency of nested ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I have a nested ArrayList with some numbers.

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
list.add(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
list.add(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 4 });
list.add(new Integer[] { 1, 2 });
```

How can I get the frequency of them?

With:

```
System.out.println(Collections.frequency(list , 1));
```

I only get `0` instead of `3` (in my case).

Comment: this is because none of the array are of same content and size. If you are using java 7 + then you want to use lambda and flatten it then get the frequency.

Comment: the javadoc of `Collections#frequency`: `Returns the number of elements in the specified collection equal to the specified object. More formally, returns the number of elements e in the collection such that (o == null ? e == null : o.equals(e)).`. since `list.equals(1)` wont be true at any case your result is 0.

Comment: you need to check frequency in each inner arrays, and then add values up

Comment: If your arrays are always sorted you could use Java 8 streams and grouping by toString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int count = 0;
for (Integer[] i: list) {
    count += Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(i), 1);
}
System.out.println(count);   //3
```

Answer (score 1):

proper java 8 solution will looks like that:

```
System.out.println(list.stream().mapToInt(arr -> Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(arr), 1)).sum());
```

If you are still on java 6/7  then you need to do:

```
int sum= 0;
for (Integer[] arr: list) {
    sum+=Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(arr), 1);
}
System.out.println(sum);
```